# What is the fastest and most efficient way of storing and fetching images when you have millions of users on a LAMP server?

Tags: php, linux, image, directory, lamp

Here is the best method I have come up with so far and I would like to know if there is an even better method (I'm sure there is!) for storing and fetching millions of user images:

In order to keep the directory sizes down and avoid having to make any additional calls to the DB, I am using nested directories that are calculated based on the User's unique ID as follows:

```
$firstDir = './images';
$secondDir = floor($userID / 100000);
$thirdDir = floor(substr($id, -5, 5) / 100);
$fourthDir = $userID;
$imgLocation = "$firstDir/$secondDir/$thirdDir/$fourthDir/1.jpg";
```

User ID's (`$userID`) range from 1 to the millions.

So if I have User ID `7654321`, for example, that user's first pic will be stored in:

```
./images/76/543/7654321/1.jpg
```

For User ID `654321`:

```
./images/6/543/654321/1.jpg
```

For User ID `54321` it would be:

```
./images/0/543/54321/1.jpg
```

For User ID `4321` it would be:

```
./images/0/43/4321/1.jpg
```

For User ID `321` it would be:

```
./images/0/3/321/1.jpg
```

For User ID `21` it would be:

```
./images/0/0/21/1.jpg
```

For User ID `1` it would be:

```
./images/0/0/1/1.jpg
```

This ensures that with up to 100,000,000 users, I will never have a directory with more than 1,000 sub-directories, so it seems to keep things clean and efficient.

I benchmarked this method against using the following "hash" method that uses the fastest hash method available in PHP (crc32).  This "hash" method calculates the Second Directory as the first 3 characters in the hash of the User ID and the Third Directory as the next 3 character in order to distribute the files randomly but evenly as follows:

```
$hash = crc32($userID);
$firstDir = './images';
$secondDir = substr($hash,0,3);
$thirdDir = substr($hash,3,3);
$fourthDir = $userID;
$imgLocation = "$firstDir/$secondDir/$thirdDir/$fourthDir/1.jpg";
```

However, this "hash" method is slower than the method I described earlier above, so it's no good.

I then went one step further and found an even faster method of calculating the Third Directory in my original example (`floor(substr($userID, -5, 5) / 100);`) as follows:

```
$thirdDir = floor(substr($userID, -5, 3));
```

Now, this changes how/where the first 10,000 User ID's are stored, making some third directories have either 1 user sub-directory or 111 instead of 100, but it has the advantage of being faster since we do not have to divide by 100, so I think it is worth it in the long-run.

Once the directory structure is defined, here is how I plan on storing the actual individual images: if a user uploads a 2nd pic, for example, it would go in the same directory as their first pic, but it would be named `2.jpg`.  The default pic of the user would always just be `1.jpg`, so if they decide to make their 2nd pic the default pic, `2.jpg` would be renamed to `1.jpg` and `1.jpg` would be renamed `2.jpg`.

Last but not least, if I needed to store multiple sizes of the same image, I would store them as follows for User ID 1 (for example):

1024px:

```
./images/0/0/1/1024/1.jpg
./images/0/0/1/1024/2.jpg
```

640px:

```
./images/0/0/1/640/1.jpg
./images/0/0/1/640/2.jpg
```

That's about it.

So, are there any flaws with this method?  If so, could you please point them out?

Is there a better method?  If so, could you please describe it?

Before I embark on implementing this, I want to make sure I have the best, fastest, and most efficient method for storing and retrieving images so that I don't have to change it again.

Thanks!

Comment: I sure hope nothing you're storing/accessing this way is private or confidential, as it becomes extremely easy to browse to other users' image folders

Comment: Privacy isn't a concern in my case, so that shouldn't be a problem.  My users want their pics to be seen.  For the sake of thoroughness, if privacy were a concern, what solution would you recommend?

Comment: The fastest way to load millions of images is _not to load them_. That is, use `memcached`, and rely on the assumption that 95% of the users want to see the same 5% of the images all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do *not* care about the small speed differences of calculting the path, it *doesn't* matter. What matters is how well and uniformly the images are distributed in the directories, how short is generated the path, how hard is it to deduce the naming convention (lets replace 1.jpg to 2.jpg.. wow, it's working..).

For example in your hash solution the path is entirely based on userid, which will put all pictures belonging to one user to the same directory.

Use the whole alphabet (lower and uppercase, if your FS supports it), not just numbers. Check what other softwares do, a good place to check hashed directy names is google chrome, mozilla, ... It's better to have short directory names. Faster to look up, occupies less space in your html documents.

Comment: But won't the small speed differences/CPU-required be significantly magnified once you have millions of users interacting simultaneously with the Server?

Comment: @Programmer if such a small difference in efficiency makes your site unusable, then you should be using a server farm to scale out your site. There are bigger and more important concerns than just efficiency, such as security. Performing security checks isn't "efficient", but how fast your page loads doesn't matter if you lose all your users. If you really have millions of users and can't afford a server farm, then you probably need to re-think your business model.

Comment: *everything* is going to be magnified.

Comment: @Joel C:  I see it slightly different, if you can make code - any code - faster with no serious downsides, why not?

Comment: Depends on how you define "serious downsides", I suppose. There are always tradeoffs, and the job of the developer/system architect is to balance those tradeoffs. If you truly want the greatest level of efficiency, why are you writing your site in PHP? Use assembly, it's more efficient.

Comment: no downsides? `images/76/543/7654321/101.jpg` could be `i/a7/c3/5e.jpg` that's less than half of the original size.

Comment: @Joel C: But I'm referring to the context of my post.  Are you saying there are serious downsides to the method I posted about vs. a better method?

Comment: @yi_H: What are the downsides of a longer URL for the image?

Comment: haven't you read my answer? that's one less directory lookup, that's already worth it. shortert urls mean shorter generated documents. BTW nowadays the main metric for efficiency is primary the development time. hardware is cheap.

Comment: @yi_H:  Yes, I read your answer, but I'm still not clear on the downsides of the method I posted.  For example, the solution I posted also bases the entire path on the userid, so it also puts all the pictures belonging to one user to the same directory.  The only downside I can see is a longer URL, but what negative effect does that have that compensates for a faster code execution?  That's what I'm trying to understand.