# What are the downsides of longer directory paths/names and URL's on a LAMP site?

Tags: php, linux, image, directory, lamp

What are the downsides of longer directory paths/names and URL's on a LAMP site?

I am trying to organize images on my sites as efficiently as possible, and I'm keen on using many nested directories so that no sub-directory has more than 1,000 sub-directories.

In a worst-case scenario, images would be stored looking something like this:

```
./images/76/543/7654321/640/1.jpg
```

Are there any serious downsides to having so many sub-directories vs. something simpler like this:

```
./i/a7/c3/5e.jpg
```

I suppose the more sub-directories the Server has to dig in to, the longer it's going to take, and the longer the directory structure is, the longer the URL will be, so the more space the HREF will take up in the HTML doc.  But how much of a difference will that make?  Let's say we scale up to millions of users, is this something I need to take into consideration (short dir structure vs long dir structrue)?

For context, please view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877771/what-is-the-fastest-and-most-efficient-way-of-storing-and-fetching-images-when-yo).

Thanks!

Comment: As yi_H said, do not care about it, the distribution of the files across directories is more important than the length of the name.

Comment: @afuzzyllama:  Thanks for your input.  Since the distribution across directories is even with the method I'm wanting to use, does that mean it's OK even though the length of the directory names is longer and it uses additional sub-directories?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you are really worried about the performance you should try running some benchmarks.

Comment: @afuzzyllama:  I did run benchmarks on how long it takes to CALCULATE the directory structure in PHP in order to know what image to seek based on the User ID and the method I presented was faster than the hash-based method...

Comment: @afuzzyllama:  However, it was brought to my attention that using additional sub-directories could slow things down, so I'm not sure which method to go for and I'm having a hard time getting a straight answer from anyone (hence why I created this second post, after my first)...perhaps I'm not getting a straight answer because there isn't one, and it just depends, in which case I should just use the method I mentioned and move forward since it is more convenient?  What do you think?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a large number of files in one directory can make it slow. You are right to split it up. You can however try to reduce the length by using all alphanumeric characters in the path names.

If you were to have:

```
/images/[a-z0-9]{3}/[a-z0-9]{3}/[a-z0-9]{3}.jpg
/images/abc/def/ghi.jpg
```

With the above you can store 101559956668416 images. This seems ridiculous so perhaps something like:

```
/images/[a-z0-9]{2}/[a-z0-9]{2}.jpg
/images/ab/cd.jpg
```

With the above you can store 1679616 images. This is a reasonable number but might not be enough for your needs. So how about this:

```
/images/[a-z0-9]{2}/[a-z0-9]{2}/[a-z0-9]{2}.jpg
/images/ab/cd/ef.jpg
```

This allows for 2176782336 (2 billion) images and each directory will only ever have a maximum of 1296 child files/directories.

Mix in some capital letters and perhaps even some symbols and you can get away with even fewer. 
Personally I would go with the last option though. It seems to be a nice balance.

Comment: Thanks freshwire.  But what specifically are the downsides to using extra sub-directories in a path and longer directory names?  The reason I ask is because with the method I'm wanting to use, it makes it really simple to organize user files, especially user albums and images in different sizes, so I'm trying to ascertain the downsides of using longer and additional directories to determine whether it is worth it or not.  Please let me know and thanks again!